# Excel iterate through rows in 2 sheets and capturing the data on specific rows

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?
I just need to get some cell contents on matches from one sheet to the other.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim myValue As String
i = 2
j = 3

Do While Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    myValue = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Do While Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value <> ""
        If Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = myValue Then

            If (Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 3).Value) And (Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 4).Value) And (Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 5).Value) And (Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 6).Value) Then

                Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 18).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If







        End If
        j = j + 1 'go to the next row in your second sheet
    Loop

    i = i + 1 'go to the next row in your first sheet
    j = 3 'now we are going to iterate the next row of the first sheet, so we want to reset the position in our second sheet
Loop
End Sub
```

Right now it is not editing the cell I specified after that really long IF statement.

Comment: That's not at all clear. All your code does is check if a cell is blank.

Comment: Do you already try to do that with formulas?, Index and Match?

Comment: I dont think you can use formulas on this cause it needs to iterate over the entire worksheet and check for matches with the 2nd sheet. I know it has to be a nested For Loop, I'm just not sure how to set it up on VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write some code to achieve your task, but I really don't fully understand your question:

```
Sub myFunc()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim myValue As String
    i = 1
    j = 1

    Do While Worksheets("myFirstSheet").Cells(i, 1).value <> "" 'I assume that when a cell is empty then we reached the end of your table
        myValue = Worksheets("myFirstSheet").Cells(i, 1).value 'I save the value of the cell in a variable

        Do While Worksheets("mySecondSheet").Cells(j, 1).value <> "" 'I assume that when a cell is empty then we reached the end of your table
            If Worksheets("mySecondSheet").Cells(j, 1).value = myValue Then 'if that value equals one of the cells of your second sheet...
                doSomethingFunc 'we have to write it
            End If
            j = j + 1 'go to the next row in your second sheet
        Loop

        i = i + 1 'go to the next row in your first sheet
        j = 1 'now we are going to iterate the next row of the first sheet, so we want to reset the position in our second sheet
    Loop

End Sub
```

Now, this code iterates through all records of the first sheet and when in the second sheet meets a record which equals one of the first sheet calls the function `doSomethingFunc`. It compares the first column of the two sheets.
If the names of your sheets change then you'd better create a userForm (if you need to I can explain, but don't worry it is very easy).

Now we have to write the `doSomethingFunc`. So, what do you want it to happen when it finds two equals rows?

Sorry for my bad English!

---

**EDIT 1:**

These are the *fictitious* databases:

**`sheet1`**: [image]

**`sheet2`**: [image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. 
I can manage the doSomethingFunc part. The Loop is what I really needed help with. Thanks!

Comment: @zscratch perfect, you are welcome! Don't esistate to ask if you have issues.

Comment: I edited the question to do what I wanted it to do. It hasn't quite worked. Could you take a look?

Comment: @zscratch what is the problem? I've tried the code you posted on a _fictitious_ database and it worked as I expected. It loops over all the non-empty cells of the first column of `sheet1` and for each of these checks if it is the same as one of the cells of the first column of `sheet2`. If it finds a match then it compare the cells of the if-statement. If **all** the conditions of the if-statement are true then it puts in the cell at the 18th column of `sheet2` (so column `R`) and at the row where it found the match the value of the cell at the third column of `sheet1` (so column `C`).

Comment: Hmm ... it didn't seem to work for me. I'm probably running it on a bad database then. Thanks for checking

Comment: yep, I double checked and the data i needed to match initially was actually on column 2 on one of the sheets, so my If statement was never being executed. Got it now. Thanks alot! you're awesome!

Comment: @zscratch I edited the answer and added the images of database I used, you can try to check if they follow the same logic of yours.

Comment: @zscratch oh sorry, I didn't notice you solved your issue. Mistakes as the one you made are very common and hard to find, it happend to me a lot of times! Glad I helped solving the problem, you are welcome!